# What are Action GET_FINGERPRINT etc that appears on console (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, redux

I was visiting a website and opened the console and saw these. 
Do these actions have a name? What are they used for? I tried searching google for their specific names but no luck. (I hid some number information as I don't know what they may represent)

My thoughts so far is to identify if the user is an actual user and not a bot by running some scripts.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [Redux Middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) logs, which are great for debugging. They allow you to view all the state changes going on. I'm not sure it's meant to be left in on a live website though. The output is generated via the [Redux Logger](https://github.com/theaqua/redux-logger).

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Maybe you can help me understand what these GET_USER_AGENT etc do as well? Are these specific names for the site or generic names for a specific library?

Comment: @lordanis These are `actions` that get passed to `reducers`, that are used to calculate a new state based on the old and the action. It's a concept of the Redux framework that can be used with React JS. See: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html for more information. I plan on learning this myself when I get a chance.